# Visio 2010 Data Model from an Existing Netezza Database

Tags: refresh, database-schema, visio

I'm looking to build a Visio data model from an existing database.

I open Visio, select the option to create a new document from a data model, and select the Database tab.

The Database is Netezza, so I'm using **Generic OLE DB Provider** and the **IBM Netezza OLE DB Data Provider**

[image: Generic OLE DB Provider]
[image: IBM Netezza OLE DB Data Provider]

I complete the wizard entering the correct Data Source and username/password...
[image: Connection]

When I test the connection I get an "Connection Successful"

...But when I click "OK" The connection disappears. There appears to be a "Save" button missing. Is this a bug in Visio? Am I missing a step?

Thanks for advice/ thoughts/ comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you when I try to 'Link Data to Shapes' from Netezza, I get an error box that says "Microsoft Visio cannot connect to this data source" with detail message "Error 80040e21: ODBC driver does not support the requested properties." using ODBC. Using OLE DB, I got the same error the first time. Trying to reproduce it for you to retrieve the specific OLE DB error, I've crashed Visio twice.

I believe the situation is hopeless. Visio is making driver calls that IBM does not support in its drivers.

Ooh! The answer was, as always, to keep plugging away. The 'reverse engineer' on the Database tab... or subribbon... seems to have successfully pulled objects out of my Netezza database. It threw a lot of function sequence errors, but I have no way of interpreting those, and they don't seem to have damaged anything.

I used the 'Microsoft Access' driver with the 'Netezza' data source, which makes an ODBC connection. It had a warning about using Microsoft Access and Netezza, but I don't know what ostensible role Access was playing, here. The fields and table/view names came in.